# Polynomials and orthogonality

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be the vector space of all polynomials $f$ of the form
$$f : x → a_0 + a_1x + a_2x^2$$

for all real x such that $0 ≤ x ≤ 1$. Here $a_0, a_1, a_2$ are real numbers. Prove that $V$ is a three-dimensional space over R. Show that
$$(f, g) = ∫^1_0 f(x)g(x)dx$$
is an inner product on $V$. Find a function $f$ such that $f$ is orthogonal to $x$, orthogonal to $x^2$, and $∥f∥ = 1$.

Here is How I approach:

$\{1,x,x^2\}$ is a basis of $f(x)$ at degree 2. $V$ is a three dimensional space over $R$ by the definition of dimension.

Then I show that $$(f, g) = ∫^1_0 f(x)g(x)dx$$ by the properties of inner product: positivity, additivity in first slot and homogeneity in first slot.

But, I got stuck finding function $f$. I guess I need to show $\langle f,f \rangle = f_0f_0+f_1f_1+f_2f_2 = 1 $ to satisfy $||f||=1$. But I don't know how to find function $f$ that is orthogonal to $f$ and $f^2$.

Thanks in advance! Suggestions and helps are needed!

Comment: First, curly parentheses: $\;\{1,x,x^2\}\;$ , and second: that is **a**  basis, not *the* basis. Hopefully you did prove this. Also, what do you mean with "first slot"? The first variable? Then no: this is a real vector space with inner product, which **must** be linear in *both* variables.

Comment: Here is what I mean by additivity in first slot: for instance => $\langle u+v,w\rangle = \langle u,w\rangle+\langle v,w\rangle$ for all $u,v,w \in V$. Is it not enough to prove by definition that $V$ is three dimensional space over $R$?

Comment: I think I misunderstood your question.  Which parts remain to be proved? If you have already shown that the properties of the inner product apply, then you have proved that the integral is an inner product.

Comment: Well then, I guess I just need to show the properties of inner product apply to integral to prove that the integral is an inner product.

Answer (score 1):

There are two natural approaches to find $f$:

1. Let $f=a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2$.  $0=\langle f,x\rangle$ will give you a linear equation in $a_0, a_1, a_2$.  Then $0=\langle f,x^2\rangle$ will give you another such.  You can then either take any solution and normalize, or get a third (nonlinear) equation from $1=\langle f,f\rangle$.
2. If $\{x,x^2\}$ were orthogonal, you could subtract the projection of $f$ onto each of them, and the result would be orthogonal to both (much like in Gram-Schmidt).  Hence instead you could use GS to find an orthogonal basis for Span($x,x^2$), then subtract the projection of $f$ onto each of these vectors.

Comment: Thanks, do i need to find an orthogonal basis in this case?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: We want a polynomial $p:p(x)=\alpha_0+\alpha_1x+\alpha_2x^2$, such that$$\begin{array}{rcl} \langle p,x\rangle & = & 0 \\ \langle p,x^2\rangle &=&0\\\langle p,p\rangle &=&1 \end{array}$$

Comment: then $p(x) = 1 + 0 x + 0 x^2$ would be function. What would you say about my answers to the first two question? Thanks for your hint tough!

Comment: No, that still doesn't satisfy the first two.  The inner product with x would give $\int^1_0xdx$, which is not zero.

Comment: So it is not enough to prove that $V$ is three dimensional space over $R$ by definition of dimension? I am still confused how to show that the integration is an inner product on $V$.

Comment: @needhelp, showing that this is an inner product is the second part of the problem.  End.  The third part is to find the polynomial $f$ satisfying all the various conditions, *using* the inner product -- this is the part that the two solutions are about.